# Teamcity & Git - PR merge builds - anyway to get HEAD commit hash?

Tags: github, teamcity

I've got a team city build project with a github vcs root. I've got builds triggering on PR for both the /head and /merge refs. The annoying thing is though you can't do anything useful with the merge commit hash - it doesn't exist in github. I'd like to push out nuget packages with the hash (substring 7) in the version number and github commit statuses for the merge build but against the HEAD hash.

However I can't see a way to get that HEAD hash while it's building the merge. I don't just want to do head as it's kind of useless - we only care the merge will build.

(PR - pull requests)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command seems to work reliably when run on a /merge.

```
git log --no-merges -1 --pretty='%H'
```